# Is there a vscode settings which specifies which tab to open when closing a tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After you've close a tab in vscode, the most recently viewed tab gets focus. I would like to change that behavior to instead focus the tab to the right of the closed tab.

Is there a setting to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was added in release 1.31 in January 2019. From the [changelog](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_closing-order-of-editor-tabs):

> ## Closing order of editor tabs
>
> A new setting `workbench.editor.focusRecentEditorAfterClose` allows you to change the order in which editor tabs are closed. By default, tabs will close in most recently used (MRU) order. Changing this setting allows closing tabs from right to left instead.

So adding `"workbench.editor.focusRecentEditorAfterClose": false` to your `settings.json` should give you the behaviour you want.