# How to get Visual Studio code to select the correct tab when closing the current tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I close a tab in Visual Studio Code, I would like it to behave like every other tabbed editor/browser I use when closing a tab.

I have already read the answer given to [Is there a vscode settings which specifies which tab to open when closing a tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909028/is-there-a-vscode-settings-which-specifies-which-tab-to-open-when-closing-a-tab), which implies that setting `"workbench.editor.focusRecentEditorAfterClose": false` in `settings.json` will give the desired behaviour — unfortunately, it does not.

Given five tabs `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and that tab `C` is currently selected:

- When I press the `close tab` shortcut, every other program I've used leaves tab `B` selected — *ie* it closes to the left.
- Visual Studio Code leaves tab `D` selected — *ie* it closes to the right. This drives me mad, as if I close two tabs in succession, the *wrong* tab is closed for the second close action.

There's nothing particularly *wrong* about closing to the right instead of the left, except for the fact that virtually every other program closes to the left. It's equivalent to putting a search box on a website and having a search for "foo bar" perform "foo **or** bar" rather than "foo **and** bar" — since Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo, eBay, Amazon, Twitter and Facebook (to name but a few major sites) all use **and**, it needlessly confuses people and slows them down.

I can't find a setting to configure this, nor can I find anything in the Marketplace that might fix it. Is it possible?

Comment: VSC uses Chrome and this close to the right is the Chrome behavior. Add a feature request

Comment: What keybinding are you using to close an editor?  Ctrl+W?

Comment: I would argue precisely the opposite—that closing "to the right" is the *correct, standard* tab closing behaviour. Reason: that is the current behaviour in both Firefox *and* Chrome, and those two programs are likely the most-used tab applications in the whole world (with the possible exception of whatever's the current top internet browser in China). As a result I'd say that most people are probably more familiar and comfortable with that particular tab closing behaviour.

Comment: @eriegz That still doesn't explain why there isn't an option, though, considering the size of the preferences list :) In any case, while *browsers* may close to the right, all the other IDEs I've used close to the left. VS Code may be based on Chrome, but it's still an IDE, not a browser, so should work like an IDE, not a browser…

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own macro to accomplish what you want.  You need a macro because you need to run two commands: close your editor and then focus the editor to the left.  I don't believe there is any built-in way to do it otherwise.

So, using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), this goes into your settings:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.closeEditorFocusLeft",
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor",
      "workbench.action.previousEditor",
    ]
  }
]
```

and a keybinding in keybinding.json:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "-workbench.action.closeActiveEditor"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "command": "multiCommand.closeEditorFocusLeft"
    },
    // "when": "editorFocus"
  },
```

I assumed here that you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the active editor, and I first disabled the default command for that and then assigned it to the macro.  But you could whatever keybinding you wish.  And it works.

In my testing it is **required** to have the setting

```
Workbench > Editor: Focus Recent Editor On Close
```

**disabled**.  So that vscode actually tries to go right instead of to the most recently opened editor wherever that may be (and then go to the left of that).

Unfortunately, outside of an extension, I thinkthis is the only way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks — I don't suppose there is a way to get it to only run if the current tab is not the leftmost? I've tried setting `editorFocus && activeEditorGroupIndex != '1'` on the macro, and `editorFocus && activeEditorGroupIndex == '1'` on the original `View: Close Editor` but it ignores the macro and closes right unless I disable `View: Close Editor` completely — and then closing the leftmost tab leaves the rightmost tab selected, which is the Wrong Thing™.

Comment: There is another problem. If (tab count>=3) && (the current tab is the rightmost). Press "ctrl+w" will make current tab move left twice.  
ie: 1, 2, 3, [4] -> 1, [2], 3