# Have VSCode close tabs from right to left

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, when I press ctrl+w to close a tab in VSCode, it will close the tab, and then jump to the last used tab as the active tab.

Is there a way I can have vscode always just jump to the tab to the left of the tab that I just closed?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239964/836330

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to settings, search for `Workbench › Editor: Focus Recent Editor After Close` and unselect it.

That is the same than adding this line to your `settings.json` file. `"workbench.editor.focusRecentEditorAfterClose": false`

Comment: But that focuses the editor to the **right** of the closed one - the question is about focusing to the **left**.